# Variable Resistance in LTspice- Convergence problems + understanding the solver

Tags: surge-protection, over-voltage-protection, varistor, mov

I've created a variable resitance model in LTspice to simulate the behavior of a Metal Oxide Varistor. The variable resistance is performed with a behavioral source aas follows:

[image]

```
V={-(V(6)<-1m)*(-K11*(-V(6))**(a11-1)-K22*(-V(6))**(a22-1))-K33*(-V(6))**(a33-1) + (V(6)<=1m)*(V(6)>=-1m)*(m*1k) + (V(6)>1m)*(K11*V(6)**(a11-1) + K22*V(6)**(a22-1) + K33*V(6)**(a33-1))}
```

I want to test this model against and impulse current wave and the schematic is shown below:

[image]

[image]

This model consists of a variable resistance with a series inductor. (There is a paralel capacitor in the standard model but I'm not modeling since I have convergence problems, that btw I dont fully understand. Either way its effect its not that reelvant in my aplication so I will be ingoring it.)

The simulation works fine up until I charge the capacitor to around 50kV, after that the typical "Time step too small" error apears and the simulation stops mid way. To solve that I added a paralel capacitor. And somehow the capacitor solves the problem only when it has a value of 1e-16 when I set the charging voltage to 50kV but if increase it to 55kV then it has to be around 1e-18.

[image]

My questions are,

· What is the reason to why adding the capacitor solves the convergence problem?

· Why does it only work when it is below a certain value?

· Is there a way to addapt this sort of solution to other circuits?

--------------------Additional info--------------------------------------

For a charging voltage of 55kV this is the voltage and current across the MOV,

[image]